# Refresh div on interval

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to reload some div on a page, I have done some research and most of it said that jQuery is the simplest way to do it. But i've never used jQuery before.

Can anyone help me with this?

Sorry for this ambiguous question. Let me narrow it down a little bit

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:400px; float:left" id="test">
    <table border="0" width="" style="table-layout: fixed; height: 400px;" >
         <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font-size:xx-large; width: 283px; font-family: Rockwell;border-color:#3366CC; border-style:solid" bgcolor="#3366CC">
                <asp:Label ID="lblHeaderLoket" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font-size:xx-large; font-family: 'Segoe Script'; width: 283px;border-color:#3366CC; border-style:solid">
                <asp:Label ID="lblHeaderPlatNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

**C#**

```
private void BindHeaderObject()
{
    CriteriaComposite cc = new CriteriaComposite(new Criteria(typeof(BoardQueue), "RowStatus", (short)DBRowStatus.Active));
    cc.And(new Criteria(typeof(BoardQueue), "Status", (short)CallCustomerStatus.Open));

    Collection<BoardQueue> collBoardQueue = new ServiceFacade(User).SelectList<BoardQueue>(cc);

    if (collBoardQueue.Count != 0)
    {
        Counter counter = new ServiceFacade(User).SelectById<Counter>(collBoardQueue[0].CounterID);

        lblHeaderLoket.Text = counter.Name;
        lblHeaderPlatNumber.Text = collBoardQueue[0].PlatNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        lblHeaderLoket.Text = "-";
        lblHeaderPlatNumber.Text = "-";
    }
}
```

Wat I want is to refresh that div only, not the entire page. Every time it refreshes, it will get latest data from database.

Comment: What will `refresh` do?

Comment: @void so i have a gridview inside the div which the data is from database. so everytime it refresh i want it to get new data from database

Comment: For that you should ready about `AJAX`

Comment: You are on `.net` platform and you are using `gridview` controll i guess. So if you want to refresh then why don't you reload the page or as suggested by void use ajax.

Comment: Here some tutorials that help you: http://www.dotnetspan.com/2015/02/bind-gridview-using-jquery-json-ajaxcall-in-aspnet.html and http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-Dataset-to-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx. Basically, you can google it: `asp.net gridview jquery ajax`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the jQuery AJAX function.

You must create a file you gonna call in ajax and post to your div.

There is an exemple :

AJAX part (in JS) :

```
var oAjaxCall = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./someAction.php",
    success: function(data){
        $('#refreshDiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

`data`is the return of `someAction.php`. Remember that : You can't do a "return" in `someAction.php`. You should echo your content with `echo` if you use PHP or show it in HTML normally.

The file that will create your content (someAction.php) :

```
echo 'Hello world !';
```

If you want to call it after 1 min for exemple, use setInterval();

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)'s the jQuery Ajax function documentation and you can find the documentation for setInterval function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

If you want, I can write a little function to show you how to do that :)

Comment: I forgot to tell you. `data` is the return of `someAction.php`. And sorry if you don't understand my answer but I don't speak english very well.

Comment: you can edit your answer and add this comment to it.

Comment: Wow 'SatanicGeek'... you must be using `eval()` a lot

Comment: Can you explain what's `eval()` ?

Answer (score 0):

**1. jQuery approach**

I see that there's no point if you're using asp.net server control to update a table inside a client control.
What I suggest is to use jQuery Ajax to call a web method which returns the update data and list it on table in HTML. This is much lightweight solution than using server control.

**2. Server Control approach**

What you mean by refreshing the `div` for each interval might be using `UpdatePanel` server control. You put your `GridView` inside `ContentTemplate` in `UpdatePanel`. And set the `UpdateMode` to `conditional`.

Eventually, your `UpdatePanel` will render as a `div`. And you may name any classes to it.

While, you also have a `Timer` control which updates your `UpdatePanel` for `x` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to reload Div/Table data after Every "N" seconds Interval, use jQuery SetInterval method.

Inside the set Interval, u can invoke the Ajax call and update the data in the Ajax Success Block.

Ex:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
$.ajax({
url: "YouUrl",
success: function(response){
   //Code to update the Table or Div
}

}); 

}, 3000);
```